# Slow SSH WLAN PI 3

Tags: pi-3, ssh, wifi

In my home network my SSH connection was really slow and sometimes it just freezed when I typed in commands after I connected to my PI succesfully.

Surprisingly the SSH connection worked much faster when I connected via **weaved** so I guessed that there is a problem with my WLAN Router.

Update:

**weaved** changed its name to **remot3.it**

Comment: This isn't a question. This is a question with an answer. EDIT your question to cut the answer out, then click on ANSWER and paste your answer there. Otherwise your question is going to float around forever without an official answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found following **FIX:**

**I switched my router's radio channel**  to another one, that wasn't used by others that much.

Now SSH works like charm on my PI.

Comment: Once I have enabled two different SSID names to distinguish 2.4GHz from 5GHz radio channels on my router (not by default), SSH has started to works normally. I guess it's a similar issue.